# regex breaking Chinese string

Tags: php, regex, cjk

When i run this code and similar some Chinese the ni (你） character (maybe others) gets chopped of and broken.

```
$sample = "你不喜欢 香蕉 吗";
$parts = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $sample);
var_dump($parts);

//outputs
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "�"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "不喜欢"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "香蕉"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "吗"
}

//in 我觉得 你很 麻烦
//out
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "我觉得"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "�"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "很"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "麻烦"
}
```

Is my regex wrong?

Comment: Your regex must be correct. I am not a php guy but when I tried in java this works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your string is in UTF-8, you must use the `u` modifier:

```
$sample = "你不喜欢 香蕉 吗";
$parts = preg_split("/[\\s,]+/u", $sample);
var_dump($parts);
```

If it's in another encoding, see unicornaddict's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368667/regex-breaking-chinese-string/3368694#3368694).

Answer (score 0):

Since the input string is multi-byte, I guess you'll have to use [`mb_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-split.php) in place of preg_split.

Comment: if i use mb_split i  only get `string(25) "我觉得  你很  麻烦"` as output (double space?)

Comment: @Moak With mb_split you can't add delimiters. You specify the global modifiers in another parameter.